# Inversion of a matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, tensors, multilinear-algebra, index-notation

Is there a general way to invert (solve for $u$) this?
$$\sum_{ij}R_{ijk}a_iu_j = -x_k$$
With $a,u,x \in \mathbb{R}^N$. $R_{ijk}$ is symmetric in the last two indices.
So really I'm trying to invert this:
$$A= \begin{bmatrix} a'R_1 \\ a'R_2 \\ ...\\ a'R_N \end{bmatrix}$$
Could there be a nice formula for this inverse if all the $R_i$ are invertible? If you multiply $A$ by a matrix that has as columns $R_i^{-1}a$ you get that it's equal to $a'aI_n+ E$ where $E$ is traceless (it has $0$ in every element of the diagonal).

Comment: This or "something like" this? If the matrix $(\sum\limits_iR_{ijk}a_i)_{kj}$ is invertible: yes.

Comment: This. The "something like" came out of the fact that I was considering a more general problem but the equations would be exactly the same redefining $x$. I edited.

Comment: Forgive me that in math I am quite allergic against the term "something like". I wish you  a happy matrix inversion. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave the bounty to greg because of really nice matrix calculus (and helpfulness in general). What I was looking for precisely was something along the lines of this formula:
$$A^{-1} = \frac{1}{|A|}\text{adj} A$$
And from this I can say that the numerator is a polynomial in $a$ of degree $n-1$ and the denominator a polynomial of degree $n$.

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\p{\partial} \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\R{{\cal R}} \def\qif{\quad\iff\quad}
\def\Si{S^{-1}}  \def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\Sp{S^{\bf+}}
\def\Sh{{\widehat S}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
$Contracting the vector $a$ with the **first component** of the
third-order tensor $\R$ yields
$$ S=a\cdot\R \qif S_{jk} = \sum_i\,a_i\,\R_{ijk} $$
The fact that $\R$ is symmetric in its last two $(jk)$ indices
means that $S$ is a symmetric matrix.

This leaves a symmetric linear system to be solved for $u$
$$x=-S\cdot u \qiq u=-\Si x$$

Introducing the indexed matrices $\left(R_k = \R_{ijk}\right)\,$
seems like an unnecessary complication.

${\sf NB\!:\: If}\;S^{-1}$ does not exist, then there is no solution and you must settle for a least-squares approximation
via the pseudoinverse $S^{\bf+}$ and an arbitrary vector $b$
$$u=-\Sp x \;+\; \LR{I-\Sp S}b$$

### Update

Although not stated in the question, your comments indicate that you're also interested in the dependence of the solution $u$ on the other vectors in the problem.

For $x$ this is straightforward
$$ \c{\grad ux = -\Si} $$
For $a$ it is more complicated.
First we'll need the effect of changes to $S$ on $\Si$
$$\eqalign{
S\Si &= I \qiq
S\,d\Si + dS\,\Si = 0 \\
d\Si &= -\Si\,dS\,\Si \\
}$$
The effect on $u$ is therefore
$$\eqalign{
du &= -d\Si x \\
   &= +\LR{\Si\,dS\,\Si}x \\
\grad u{a_k} &= \Si\gradLR S{a_k}\Si x \\
}$$
Next, we need to interpret the component-wise gradient of $S$.

Define the indexed matrix $\Sh_i$ with components
$$\eqalign{
\LR{\Sh_i}_{jk} &= \R_{ijk} \\
}$$
Use these to construct and differentiate the $S$ matrix itself
$$\eqalign{
S &= a_1\Sh_1 + a_2\Sh_2 + \ldots \qiq
\grad S{a_k} &= \Sh_k \\
}$$
Substituting yields the desired gradient
$$ \c{\grad u{a_k} = \Si \Sh_k \Si x} $$
The component-wise gradient of $S$ also gives us
$$ d\Si = -\Si\,dS\,\Si \qiq\grad\Si{a_k} = -\Si \Sh_k \Si $$

Comment: Suppose $S$ is invertible. Do I know the form of the coefficients for the inverse (say: are they quadratic in $a$?)?

Comment: Neat! Yeah, I wrote exactly what I was looking for in the bounty. But what about the dependence of $S^{-1}$  from $a$?